# exception while drawing in xna when a new monitor is plugged

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, xna, multiple-monitors

I'm having a problem with my xna solution.
When I plug a new monitor to my computer while running my xna solution, I get the exception:

> > Attempted to read or write protected memory. this is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

This always happens in this line:

> > mSimpleEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();

only when I plug a new monitor to my computer. I'm completely clueless.

mSimpleEffect is an object of the class "BasicEffect". This line is inside the event "OnFrameRender" (inside a try block that doesn't catch it) that is called every time the program is going to Render a new frame.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not pretty sure if that will help but ia hade a simular problem by rendering with WPF/OSG and resizing the window

it lock like when you plugin a monitor the resolution is changing and you rendering buffer changes esspecially when you ar in fullscreen. 
by the change of the resolution the enging try's to render into the same buffersize by having not enougth place in the buffer.

i don't know if that may help but i guess you need 
1. try to intercept the screensize change / or plugin message and react on it like by resolution change

```
 protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)


 {
        if(userClickedTheResolutionChangeButton)
        {
            graphics.IsFullScreen = userRequestedFullScreen;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = userRequestedHeight;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = userRequestedWidth;
            graphics.ApplyChanges();
        }

        // ...
    }
```

happy if that helps at least somehow, but let's wait for a pro answare :)

Comment: Thanks, but since I'm using wpf I don't know where to put that segment of code.

Comment: sins you are using XNA you have propably a class thats deriver from : Game. thats whould be the right place to override the Update function

Comment: Nope, I don't use anything that derivers from Game... I'm using GraphicsDevice

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2007/12/12/virtualizing-the-graphicsdevice-in-xna-game-studio-2-0.aspx - but also take a look on the members like devicelost, resource created of the GraphicDevice. thats all i found..